# How can I access an array stored in an object?

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++. I've been trying to figure this out for days - there'll be an easy solution no doubt but I haven't been able to find it (after much googling)! My problem is this:

I'm trying to create a class with a member function that reads in characters from a file and stores them in an array. I want to be able to create multiple objects (not sure how many - decided by the user), each with their own arrays filled with characters taken from different files. I think I've managed to do that. How would I then go about accessing the object's array in main?

The code I'm working on is long and messy but something along these lines (char.txt contains simply '12345' in this case):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Something{

public:
    void fill_array(char array_to_fill[]){
        char next;
        ifstream input;
        input.open("chars.txt");
        input.get(next);
        while(!input.eof())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
            array_to_fill[i] = next;
            input.get(next);
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Something* something = new Something[1];
    char array_to_fill[5];

    something->fill_array(array_to_fill);

    //I'd like to be able to access the array here; for example - to cout the array.

    return 0;
}
```

Apologies if a) my terminology is wrong b) my code is rubbish or c) my question is stupid/doesn't make sense. Also I should add I haven't learnt vectors yet and I'm not supposed to use them for the program I'm making. Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: The `Something` class doesn't have an array data member. You're filling an array that was created in `main`.

Comment: So to access the array you would do `array_to_fill`. As simple as that...unless you meant something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class does not store the array at all. It is simply a holder for a method. You probably want something like this, where each instance of the class holds the array. (I changed it to `std::string` since they are nicer to work with.)

```
class Something
{
    private:
        std::string data;

    public:
        void fill_data( const std::string& filename )
        {
             ifstream file( filename );
             file >> data;
             file.close();
        }

        std::string get_data() const
        {
             return data;
        }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Something> my_things;

    my_things.push_back( Something() );
    my_things[0].fill_data( "chars.txt" );
    cout << my_things[0].get_data() << std::endl;

    my_things.push_back( Something() );
    my_things[1].fill_data( "another_file.txt" );
    cout << my_things[1].get_data() << std::endl;
}
```

Since you are using C++, not C, get used to writing C++ code instead of C. (`std::vector` instead of C arrays (for unknown length arrays), `std::string` instead of `char*`, etc).

Comment: Thanks clcto, I think your answer is what I was looking for. Though I won't pretend I understand it fully! I haven't covered vectors yet but I will try and get to grips with them now. Much to learn!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is too general for the format of stack overflow, but what you want in this case is to either create a public member, or create a private member with setters and getters.

```
class Something
{
public:
    std::string m_string;
}

int main()
{
    Something A;
    A.m_string = "toto";
    cout << A.m_string;
    return 0;
}
```

Put a string for convenience (you could use a `const char*` but you will have to understand what is the scope to know when it will not be accessible anymore and you are not quite there yet) and there may be typos since I typed this from a phone.

If you really want to access the chars themselves, pass a char* with a size_t for the length of the array or use std::array if possible.

Comment: He wants to get at the elements of the array. A member variable in his class is unnecessary. He could actually make the method static if he so wish.

Comment: Then make it a char*, I think he does not understand that the string he created is only local to the scope and will have troubles later on.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. This might not be char[] specific though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments. Much appreciated. Apologies for the general/vague question - I'm new to stackoverflow and C++...lot's to learn. Will now look over your suggestions and try and understand them. Cheers!

Comment: @dlmb And don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/about) an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score -1):

Right now the method `fill_array` is creating a local copy of `array_to_fill`, so any changes that you make to `array_to_fill` only happen in the local method. To change this, pass by pointer. This way the pointer gets copied instead of the whole array object. I didn't test this but it should look more like this:

```
void fill_array(char* array_to_fill){
    ...
}
```

You don't need to change anything in the main method.

To actually access the elements you can use `[]` notation. I.e. `cout << array_to_fill[0]` in the main method.

Edit: I think that change should work.

Comment: It shouldn't take him long to test and I've used references many times.

Comment: The code doesn't compile. You're not taking the array by reference. It's actually signed as an array *of* references. You can't make an array of references.

Comment: The edit still doesn't make a difference. It's the same as the OP's code.